# Monaco Editor newline in getValue()

Tags: javascript, html, forms, newline, monaco-editor

So, i'm using Monaco Editor as a big syntax-highlighted textarea which is submitted in a form with some JavaScript. To allow this to happen, I have an `<input type="text" id="content" name="content" style="display: none;">` tag, and the JavaScript is connected to a button which does this:

```
function submitButtonClick(){
  document.getElementById("content").value = monacoeditor.getValue();
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

This works fine and does indeed submit the form, however the `getValue()` call appears to return the text in the monaco editor without the newlines. Text which looks like this in Monaco:

```
#Hello World
*I am some text*
```

is returned like so:

```
#Hello World*I am some text*
```

How can I ensure that I get the contents of the editor, including all of the newlines?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525822/how-to-set-eol-to-lf-for-windows-so-that-api-gets-value-with-n-not-r-n

Answer (score 1):

When pulling data out of Monaco, the newlines will be `/n` characters. In some situations, this will not work alone as a carriage return is also required.

```
String.replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

should fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTML's `<input type="text">` doesn't support line breaks. It is intended for single-line input (imagine usernames containing line breaks).

For multi-line input there is the `<textarea>` tag, which is just a form element like any other. Your form would then look like this:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="..." method="POST">
    <textarea id="content" name="content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</form>
```

You can then set the value of the textarea and submit the form as you did before:

```
function submitButtonClick () {
    document.getElementById ("content").value = monacoeditor.getValue ();
    document.getElementById ("myForm").submit ();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot to mention I have tried both a textarea and a text input, both having an identical effect

Comment: Can you verify that it is really Monaco not including the line breaks (e.g. with `console.log (monacoeditor.getValue ());`)? If it isn't, then this might be a transmission problem.

Comment: Yes it appears it is a transmission problem, as the newlines are indeed kept when the contents of the editor is displayed in the console using the method you suggested

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<input type="hidden" id="content" name="content" style="display: none;">`